# Changing the color of text in a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` with 3 items in my xaml:

```
<ListView Height="768" Width="220" Background="Silver" >
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
</ListView>
```

How can I change the color/text size of the text in the row?

Also as a bonus question, how can I get it so that the background of the row and the text color changes then an item is selected?

Comment: as a bonus question... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is quite simple:

If you want to set the same color for all items then the following way will be appropriate:

```
<ListView Height="768" Width="220" Background="Silver">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <system:String>Item 1</system:String>
    <system:String>Item 2</system:String>
    <system:String>Item 3</system:String>
</ListView>
```

In order for particular item to have a unique color you should place the `AlternationCount` property for the ListView itself:

```
<ListView AlternationCount="50" Height="768" Width="220" Background="Silver">
```

and a trigger within `ItemContainerStyle`. The Trigger `Value` properties here are the indexes of the items:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style> 
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

At this point it's easy to figure out how to manipulate properties other than `Foreground`.